# I want to print error-text if user will not be present in the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ejs

I want to print error-text if user will not be present in the database. But I'm unable to find, how can I do it. I'm using node, express, mongoose, mongodb, ejs.
This is my app.js file /signin post method.

```
app.post("/Signin", (req, res) => {
    Netflix.findOne({ "email": req.body.email }, { "password": req.body.password }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            if (user) {
                res.redirect("/Netflix/Movies");
            }
            else {
                res.redirect("/");
            }

        }
    });
});
```

This is my Sign.ejs file(form).

```
 <form class="Form" action="/Signin" method="POST">

                    <h1>Sign In</h1>
                    <p id="error-text">Sorry, we can't find an account with this email address. Please try again or <a
                            href="/">create a new account</a>.</p>
                    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email or phone number" name="email">
                    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                    <button onclick="validate()">Sign In</button><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
                    <label for="checkbox">
                        <p>Remember me</p>
                    </label>
                    <p class="New">New to Netflix? <span><a href="/">Sign up now.</a></span></p>
                </form>
```

This is my Signin.ejs file script.

```
script type="text/javascript">
            function validate() {

            }
        </script>
```

But for now in my Signin.css file, visibility of error-text is hidden and if user will not found in my database I want make it visible how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I"m not sure if there is a better way, correct me if I'm wrong, but you should do the signin/login requests on the front end using javascript.

So let's say you have your form:

```
<form class="Form" action="/Signin" method="POST">

                    <h1>Sign In</h1>
                    <p id="error-text">Sorry, we can't find an account with this email address. Please try again or <a
                            href="/">create a new account</a>.</p>
                    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email or phone number" name="email">
                    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                    <button onclick="validate()">Sign In</button><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
                    <label for="checkbox">
                        <p>Remember me</p>
                    </label>
                    <p class="New">New to Netflix? <span><a href="/">Sign up now.</a></span></p>
                </form>
```

So, you already have a function called validate(). In that validate function, request your to your API to sign in.

```
import axios from "axios"

validate = async function() {
  try{  
    // Get credentials
    const email = // get email;
    const password = // get password;
  
    // Make request to API
    const signin = axios({
      route: "/api/signin",
      method: "// can be POST or GET depending on how you set it"
    });
  } catch(err){
    // If theres an error, set the error message to it
    const message = err.message; // Not sure if this is the correct way to get error, but 
                                    you can check in console.log()
   document.getElementById("error-text").textContent = message;
   
  }
}
```

NOTE - make sure your signin request sends a res.cookie, otherwise it won't log you in